# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb R^3} x_3^2 e^{-\lVert x \rVert _2} \lambda_3(dx)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, spherical-coordinates

I want to calculate $$\int_{\mathbb R^3} x_3^2  e^{-\lVert x \rVert _2} \lambda_3(dx)$$
where $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

Attempt:
Parametrize $\mathbb R^3$ a.e. via the diffeomorphism $$\Psi:\,]0, \infty[ \,\times \, ]0, \pi[ \,\times\, ]-\pi, \pi[ \to \mathbb R^3 \setminus(\mathbb R_0^- \times \{0\} \times \mathbb R) \\ (r, \theta , \phi) \mapsto (r \cos \theta \sin \phi, r \sin \theta \sin \phi, r \cos \theta)$$
(change to spherical coordinates).
Since $\lVert x \rVert_2 = r$ we get
$$\int_{\mathbb R^3} x_3^2  e^{-\lVert x \rVert _2} \lambda_3(dx) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi r² \cos^2 {\theta} \,e^{-r}r^2 \sin \theta  \, d\phi d\theta dr = \\ =2\pi \int_0 ^\infty r^4e^{-r}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^2 \theta \sin \theta \, d\theta dr$$
Now substituting $u = \cos \theta$ the last integral evaluates to $$[-\frac{1}{3}\cos(\theta)]_{\theta = 0}^\pi = \frac{2}{3}.$$
With the other integral I am not sure. Of course, I can integrate by parts four times, but certainly there is a better way, maybe by expressing it through a Gauss function.
Anyhway, using Wolfram Alpha it evaluates to $24$ and we get
$$\int_{\mathbb R^3} x_3^2  e^{-\lVert x \rVert _2} \lambda_3(dx) = 32\pi.$$
Is this correct and is there a smart way to evaluate the $r^4 e^{-r} $ integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're familiar with [Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) you can notice that : $$F(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^4e^{-sx}dx = \frac{4!}{s^5}$$

and you just want $F(1) = 4! = 24$

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with these, but that seems to be a really neat identity. Is my value of $32 \pi$ correct?

Comment: @leo42 yes it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, your integral is just

$$ \frac{1}{3}\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\|x\|_2^2 e^{-\|x\|_2} \, d\mu_3 = \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty} 4\pi \rho^2\cdot \rho^2\cdot e^{-\rho}\,d\rho=\frac{4\pi}{3}\cdot 4!=\color{red}{32\pi}.$$

Comment: And the last integral evaluates to $4!$ because of the Laplace transform identity?

Comment: @leo42: $\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^n e^{-x}\,dx = n!$ by integration by parts or the integral definition of the $\Gamma$ function.